# Unit-testing ABC with helper functions in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, helper

I'm wondering if it is possible to change helper functions in a testing environment in Python. My app is structured as follows:

```
app/
  trader/
    __init__.py
    strategies/
      __init__.py
      base_strategy.py
      util.py
      models/
        __init__.py
        base_model.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    strategies/
      __init__.py
      stub_strategy.py
      test_strategies.py
      models/
        __init__.py
        stub_model.py
```

where each `base_*.py` is an abstract base class, which are inherited from in each `stub_*.py` file in the tests directory. In my `util.py` file, there is a helper function which looks through the `trader/strategies/models` directory and registers all models that are available:

```
import inspect
from . import alpha_models

existing_alpha_models = []
alpha_model_dict = {}
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(alpha_models):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
        existing_alpha_models.append(name)
        alpha_model_dict[name] = obj
```

Now to my problem: In my `BaseTradingStrategy`-class I have a method, which uses the `existing_alpha_models` list, to check if the model exists.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from .util import existing_alpha_models

class BaseTradingStrategy(ABC):
    """BaseTrading Code comes here"""
    @abstractmethod
    def some_abs_method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def register_model(self, model_name):
        if model_name not in existing_alpha_models:
            raise ValueError
```

For unit testing, I have created stub classes, which are not in the `trader/strategies/models` directory, and are, therefore, not registered in the `existing_alpha_models` list. When I want to test the functionality of the ABC with pytest, many tests fail since the method that checks the availability of the models fails. A simple solution would be to put the stub classes in the `trader` directory of my app, but I'd rather have my test code separated from the rest of the app. I probably could also make `existing_alpha_models` a property of the base class, but I don't really see the point in doing so, except making the tests pass. Is there a way to inject the stub classes in the `existing_alpha_models` for unit testing so that the test of the ABC does not fail without changing the base class too much?

--------------EDIT-------------------

I now have 2 working versions of my test code. One is using the verison of @hoefling, where I simply add the `alpha_models` to the `existing_alpha_models` list:

```
from tests.strategies import StubTradingStrategy
from tests.strategies.alpha_models import StubModel, StubModel2, StubModel3
from trader.strategies.util import existing_alpha_models
existing_alpha_models.extend(["StubModel", "StubModel2", "StubModel3"])
```

and one version where I add the models to the `alpha_models` module and reload 2 modules:

```
import importlib
from trader.strategies import alpha_models
from tests.strategies.alpha_models import StubModel, StubModel2, StubModel3

setattr(alpha_models, "StubModel", StubModel)
setattr(alpha_models, "StubModel2", StubModel2)
setattr(alpha_models, "StubModel3", StubModel3)

from nutrader.strategies import util
import nutrader.strategies.base_strategy
importlib.reload(util)
importlib.reload(nutrader.strategies.base_strategy)
from tests.strategies import StubTradingStrategy
```

The advantage of the second version is that it allows me to actually test the `util` code, but it also introduces potential risks in my test code since there exist 2 version of certain modules, which is not the case in the production environment. Is this a good idea, or should I leave it at the first version for my test environment?

Comment: `existing_alpha_models.append('foo')`?

Comment: that wouldn't work because `existing_alpha_models` is created and filled during initialization and not in the namespace of the test class, as far as I know. I also can't figure out how to access the instance that is used by the `BaseTradingStrategy` during runtime.

Comment: What initialization do you mean? As for namespacing - do you think Python will create a new shared copy of `existing_alpha_models` each time you import it? Just a do a simple test like `from util import existing_alpha_models as data; data.append('spam'); s = MyStrategy(); s.register_model('spam')` to verify that it works, then [read about how the import machinery works](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache).

Comment: To access the "instance" used by `BaseStrategy`, do `from trader.strategies.base_strategy import existing_alpha_models`. Compare it with the list imported via `from trader.strategies.util import existing_alpha_models` and you will see that it's the same instance initialized when imported for the first time, then cached and reused for all subsequent imports.

Comment: Ok, then my knowledge was simply wrong. I thought that would be more complicated and for the sub-imports in the base class extra instances of the list are created, which I couldn't simply access. Thank you for clearing that up for me. If you want to create an answer, I will accept that.

Comment: I'd rather encourage you to write an answer yourself as you now have all the necessary pieces to solve your issue. Do it and I'll upvote both the answer and the question.

Comment: I tried actually salvaging the code I have written in util.py and just append the stub classes to `trader.strategies.alpha_models` via `setattr(alpha_models, "StubModel", StubModel)`. This makes a reload of `util` necessary (since it has been imported before). But then 2 different versions of `existing_alpha_models` exist (one with `StubModel` in it, i.e. `util.existing_alpha_models`, and one without, i.e. `base_strategy.existing_alpha_models` and the test cases still fail. Is what I'm trying a bad idea due to changing and reloading a module during runtime?

Comment: Hmm, can you then update the code in your question?